# Can you put another match clause in a match arm?

Tags: rust

Can you put another match clause in one of the match results of a match like this in:

```
pub fn is_it_file(input_file: &str) -> String {
    let path3 = Path::new(input_file);  
    match path3.is_file() {
        true => "File!".to_string(),
        false => match path3.is_dir() {
                true => "Dir!".to_string(),
                _ => "Don't care",
        }
    }
}
```

If not why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, [`match` is an expression](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/book/match.html):

```
fn main() {
    fn foo() -> i8 {
        let a = true;
        let b = false;

        match a {
            true => match b {
                true => 1,
                false => 2
            },
            false => 3
        }
    }

    println!("{}", foo()); // 2
}
```

You can view the results of this on the [Rust playpen](http://is.gd/YYET7J).

The only thing that seems off about your code to me is the inconsistent usage of `.to_string()` in your code, the last match case doesn't have that.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can (see Qantas' answer). But Rust often has prettier ways to do what you want. You can do multiple matches at once by using tuples.

```
pub fn is_it_file(input_file: &str) -> String {
    let path3 = Path::new(input_file);  
    match (path3.is_file(), path3.is_dir()) {
        (true, false) => "File!",
        (false, true) => "Dir!",
        _ => "Neither or Both... bug?",
    }.to_string()
}
```